# total Ram from /proc/meminfo

Tags: java, android

i am getting in kb but i want ram in mb how i can get it as i am  getting" MemTotal: 855000kb" but i want  855mb how to get ram in Mb and how to get only number is don't want Memtotal and kb

```
public void getTotalMemory() {  
{
    String str1 = "/proc/meminfo";
    String str2;        
    String[] arrayOfString;
    long initial_memory = 0;
    try {
        FileReader localFileReader = new FileReader(str1);
        BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(    localFileReader, 8192);
        str2 = localBufferedReader.readLine();//meminfo
        arrayOfString = str2.split("\\s+");
        for (String num : arrayOfString) {
            Log.i(str2, num + "\t");
        }
        //total Memory
        initial_memory = Integer.valueOf(arrayOfString[1]).intValue() * 1024;   
        localBufferedReader.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {       
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just divide by 1000?

Comment: apply simple maths to your integer

Comment: Depends on how the system is reporting. Kilobytes are frequently reported as multiples of 1000 (as opposed to 1024) ostensibly for marketing purposes, since bigger numbers sell more units. See [Kilobyte (KB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte) vs [Kibibyte (KiB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte). :)

Comment: but hw i can remove MemTotal: kb

Comment: but hw i can remove MemTotal: kb

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to "remove MemTotal: kb"

Comment: outside of marketing there are 1024 KB in 1 MB

Comment: @user2455050 - You need to clarify your question. Are you asking how to 1) extract a numeric value from the string "MemTotal: 855000kb" 2) *Then* convert the number `855000` from kb to mb?

Comment: You needed to divide the result instead of multiplying it by 1024 I have provided updated code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 1024 KB in 1 MB, so you can divide KB by 1024, not 1000 to get MB. That is if it's truly reporting in KB (technically kibibytes, KiB). Most developers refer to a kilobyte (KB) as 1024 bytes, not 1000 bytes.

1KB = 2^10 bytes

1MB = 2^20 bytes

1GB = 2^30 bytes

Comment: but hw i can remove MemTotal:    kb

Answer (score 2):

To close a resource cleanly, replace the `close()` call inside the `try` with a call in a `finally` clause:

```
...
finally{
    try {
        if (localBufferedReader != null) {
            localBufferedReader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex to get only numbers and then use the math

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");
```

But I am not use if MemTotal always return in kb. if it is also possible to return others like mb also get the last two chars and do your calculation according to that.

sorry above code for c# :) come to dark side

```
String result = input.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have provided updated code  that provides a println of current memory in mb, Goodluck!

```
public static void getTotalMemory() {
String str1 = "/proc/meminfo";
String str2;        
String[] arrayOfString;
long initial_memory = 0;
try {
    FileReader localFileReader = new FileReader(str1);
    BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(localFileReader, 8192);
    str2 = localBufferedReader.readLine();//meminfo
    arrayOfString = str2.split("\\s+");

    for (String num : arrayOfString) {
        //System.out.println(num + "\t");
    }
    //total Memory
    initial_memory = Integer.valueOf(arrayOfString[1]).intValue();   
    initial_memory = initial_memory/1024;

    System.out.println(initial_memory);
    localBufferedReader.close();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{       
}
```

}